# Difference between namedtuples from a list of strings or a single string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple

What is the difference between these two namedtuples:

```
Point = collections.namedtuple('Point','x,y')
```

and

```
Point = collections.namedtuple('Point',['x','y'])
```

Both seem to be functionally the same for me (using python 3.8.0)

Answer (score 3):

These two namedtuples are indeed the same :-)

```
>>> import collections
>>> Point1 = collections.namedtuple('Point','x,y')
>>> Point2 = collections.namedtuple('Point',['x','y'])
>>> Point1._fields
('x', 'y')
>>> Point2._fields
('x', 'y')
```

Per the [*namedtuple()* docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

> The field_names are a sequence of strings such as ['x', 'y'].
>   Alternatively, field_names can be a single string with each fieldname
>   separated by whitespace and/or commas, for example 'x y' or 'x, y'.

Answer (score 2):

There is *no difference* between the two definitions. Named tuples support both a sequence and a comma-separated or whitespace-separated string with the names as inputs.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

> The `field_names` are a sequence of strings such as `['x', 'y']`. **Alternatively**, `field_names` can be a single string with each fieldname separated by whitespace and/or commas, for example `'x y'` or `'x, y'`.

Bold emphasis mine; the `'x, y'` or `'x y'` string syntax is merely an alternative way of spelling out the field names.

You can check the [`namedtuple._fields` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._fields) on either object to confirm that they indeed end up with the same field names:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> namedtuple('Point', 'x,y')._fields  # string, no whitespace
('x', 'y')
>>> namedtuple('Point', ('x', 'y'))._fields   # tuple, also a sequence
('x', 'y')
>>> namedtuple('Point', 'x        y')._fields   # string with lots of spaces, no comma
('x', 'y')
```